# Javascript not working with cURL or from Bat File. Any thoughts?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript that communicates with Open Broadcaster Software to trigger certain events through a websocket. The script works great when loaded into the browser but when I try to run it from a bat file or through Windows Scheduler it opens up the command prompt and just displays the javascript code.

I am 100% sure my syntax is correct in the bat file (other scripts are executing properly). I am running the script with a php extension and a WAMP stack.

Any ideas as to how to tweak this? I can share the script if necessary but this seems to be a generalized issue.

I suspect that the browser does something to render the Javascript that is missing when it runs directly from a bat file. If someone can give me a lead as to where to begin for troubleshooting, I would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks!

Comment: How do you try to execute the JavaScript code from a Batch file?

Comment: Can we see the code?

Comment: If you're trying to run JS outside the browser you may find [Node JS](https://nodejs.org/en/) to be what you're looking for

Comment: Web browsers have engines built in that compile and execute Javascript, it won't run natively on its own. As @phuzi said, you'll need Node JS to run javascript outside of a web browser

Comment: You need an environment for your JS to run. The browser provides this for you, but if you're executing your script outside of the browser then you should need to install Node.js as mentioned by a few other commenters.

Comment: Thanks guys! That is a great lead! Very much appreciated.